# flex-wrap:wrap lines don't wrap

Tags: flexbox

seems to work if I place images inside but not text

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:400px;
    word-break:break-word;
}



#list-wrapper div   {
    
    width: 150px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking and the lines of text do get wrapped if you put spaces in them, could you clarify a bit? :)

Comment: thanks.  I was looking for word-break:break-word

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `overflow-wrap` to `break-word`. This will make the text wrap inside the parent div. More about this property can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap.

```css
#list-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:400px;
}



#list-wrapper div   {
    height:150px;
    width: 150px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-wrapper">
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
           
    <div>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: actually word-break:break-word by itself works just fine